# How to find the value if it is exist in the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a SQL table called `stock`. In that table are the fields `itemcode` & `netweight`. How can I get a message like ***"The Stock is Not Available"*** if the netweight field is zero for a particular item code?

Comment: "low quality' does not even begin to describe...

Comment: Please post up what you have tried so far and why it isn't doing what you need.

Answer (score 3):

That shouldn't be a database concern in the first place; the database's job is to store (wait for it) data. So the appropriate query is just:

```
select netweight from stock where itemcode = @itemcode
```

then it is a UI concern to do something like (for example)

```
someControl.Text = netweight > 0 ? netweight.ToString()
                                 : "The Stock is Not Available";
```

However, if you *must* do it at the database, `case`:

```
select case when netweight > 0 then convert(varchar(10), netweight)
            else 'The Stock is Not Available' end as [netweight]
from stock where itemcode = @itemcode
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select 'The Stock is Not Available' 
from stock 
where netweight = 0 and 'YOUR CONDITION'
```

This is what you can use in your stored procedure.

Please give more information about table and what you need to do if you want in detail..